# Como reescrever uma URL

Tags: html, html5, htaccess, url, url-rewrite

Boa tarde pessoal. Poderiam me ajudar uma essa minha duvida ?
Queria reescrever uma URL.

Por exemplo:

```
<a href="#Contato">Contato</a>
```

que aponta para um ID da DIV Contato, porém, a URL fica:

```
https://site.com/index.php#Contato
```

e queria que ficasse:

```
https:site.com/Contato
```

Já tentei configurar o htaccess, entretanto, nada mudou :(

Comment: essa url "https:site.com/Contato" é inválida, é isso mesmo que quer fazer?

Comment: Rewrite de URLs é feita no servidor.. Numa tag `<a>` você pode colocar o link que bem entender, mas não será garantido que o servidor reconhecerá aquela URL. Procure por "urls amigáveis" na web e veja como fazem nos diferentes servidores (nginx, apache, IIS, etc..) ([uma das primeiras resposta da pesquisa](https://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis))

Comment: Link relevante: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer literalmente redirecionar para a url, basta remover o "#", ficando

```
<a href="Contato">Contato</a>
```

Agora se você quer manter a função de âncora e apenas mudar a url visualmente sem fazer um redirecionamento, você precisa do pushState do history.

Exemplo:

```
<a href="#Contato" onclick="history.pushState('Contato','Titulo contato','/Contato'); return false;">Contato</a>
```

Fonte: http://www.tidbits.com.br/pushstate-no-html-pra-mudar-a-url-do-browser-sem-dar-refresh